# Setting a property of an object inside array of objects based on a match: React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-bird-662mh

I am having this an array of objects and an object with the following structure

```
this.state = {
               arr : [ {
                        id: "val1",
                        initialVal: "test1",
                        finalVal: "final1"
                       },
                       {
                         id: "val2",
                         initialVal: "test2",
                         finalVal: "final2"
                       },
                       {
                         id: "val3",
                         initialVal: "test3",
                         finalVal: "final3"
                       },
                       {
                         id: "val4",
                         initialVal: "test3",
                         finalVal: "final3"
                       }
                     ],
                values: [ "test1","test3"]
              }

this.obj = { field: "test1" , val:6}
```

I am writing a function that takes this obj as its parameter and based on the "field" value it should set the state of "finalVal" with the "val" property of obj with the following computation(if val is greater than 5 add "ok" to the field else add "cancel") and the objects whose property don't match in the "values" array of the state its "finalVal" should be set to just blank

So the output should look after setting state :

```
 [ 
             {
              id: "val1",
              initialVal: "test1",
              finalVal: "ok"
             },
             {
              id: "val2",
              initialVal: "test2"
              finalVal: "final2"
             },
             {
              id: "val3",
              initialVal: "test3"
              finalVal: ""
             },
             {
              id: "val4",
              initialVal: "test4"
              finalVal: "final4"
             }
 ]


//What I have tried so far

 setObjState = obj => {
    console.log(obj);
    let arr = [...this.state.arr];
    let finalArr = arr.map(function(item) {
      if (item.initialVal === obj.field) {
        return { ...item, finalVal: obj.val > 5 ? "Cancel" : "Ok" };
      } else {
         if(this.state.values.includes(item.id){
              return { ...item, finalVal: "" };
          }
      }
    });
    console.log(finalArr);
    this.setState({ arr: finalArr });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need map function to update new state.

You need to fix this only:

```
setObjState = obj => {
    console.log(obj);
    let arr = [...this.state.arr];
    let finalArr = arr.map(function(item) {
      if (item.initialVal === obj.field) {
        return { ...item, finalVal: obj.val > 5 ? "Cancel" : "Ok" };
      } else {
        return { ...item, finalVal: "" };
      }
    });

    console.log(finalArr);
    this.setState({ arr: finalArr });
  }
```

Here is full code and demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-hodgkin-uxhoi

Comment: Now I have to do a computation say if val is less than 5 need to add "ok" to fieldName else "cancel" incase it is greater to the matched object. Unmatched objects fielName should be set to blank

Comment: @vjr update your question what is exact requirement do you have??

Comment: just did it:) Please check

Comment: @vjr updated code please check. You can check live version here : https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-hodgkin-uxhoi

Answer (score 1):

You should map the array, returing an object and the value of the field you want have a condition to check decide the value;

```
let filteredArr = arr.map(x => ({...x, finalVal: (x.initialVal == obj.field ? (obj.val > 5 ? "Ok" : "Cancel" ) : "")}))
this.setState({arr: filteredArr})
```

```js
let obj = { field: "test1" , val: 6}
let arr = [ {
                        id: "val1",
                        initialVal: "test1",
                        finalVal: "final1"
                       },
                       {
                         id: "val2",
                         initialVal: "test2",
                         finalVal: "final2"
                       },
                       {
                         id: "val3",
                         initialVal: "test3",
                         finalVal: "final3"
                       }
                     ]

let filteredArr = arr.map(x => ({...x, finalVal: (x.initialVal == obj.field ? (obj.val > 5 ? "Ok" : "Cancel" ) : "")}))

console.log(filteredArr)
```

Comment: @vjr please change your sample data. In arr, you don't have any numeric value. Also it's very confusing, `obj.val` is 6, but you say `if val is greater than 5 add "ok" to the field else add "cancel"`. So this means greater or equal 6 ?

Comment: @vjr just edit, not sure if it's correct, but where you are