# Prevent multiple on-click events from firing: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, dom-events, setstate

I have a situation where in I am having multiple on click events that are fired on a column header. There will be one event for filter dropdown and the other one  for sorting. There is a filter icon , on click of which column filter options will be shown. And on click of the header, sorting should also happen.

Now whenever I click on the filter icon, both handlers are getting fired. Can someone help me with this.

On click of filter icon, only filter handler should fire

Help would be appreciated.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-feather-xrpkp

### Parent

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "./styles.css";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import Child from "./Child";
interface IState {
  data: {}[];
  columns: {}[];
}

interface IProps {}

export default class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { firstName: "Jack", status: "Submitted", age: "14" },
        { firstName: "Simon", status: "Pending", age: "15" },
        { firstName: "Pete", status: "Approved", age: "17" }
      ],
      columns: []
    };
  }

  handleColumnFilter = (value: any) => {
    console.log(value);
  };

  sortHandler = () => {
    console.log("sort handler");
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let columns = [
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div onClick={this.sortHandler}>
            <div style={{ position: "absolute", marginLeft: "10px" }}>
              <Child handleFilter={this.handleColumnFilter} />
            </div>
            <span>First Name</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "firstName",
        sortable: false,
        show: true,
        displayValue: " First Name"
      },
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div onClick={this.sortHandler}>
            <span>Status</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "status",
        sortable: false
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  }

  render() {
    const { data, columns } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### Filter Component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "./styles.css";
interface IProps {
  handleFilter(val1: any): void;
}
interface IState {
  showList: boolean;
}
export default class Child extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showList: false
    };
  }

  toggleList = () => {
    console.log("filter handler");
    this.setState(prevState => ({ showList: !prevState.showList }));
  };

  render() {
    let { showList } = this.state;
    let visibleFlag: string;
    if (showList === true) visibleFlag = "visible";
    else visibleFlag = "";
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
          <div
            className={"ui scrolling dropdown column-settings " + visibleFlag}
          >
            <Icon className="filter" onClick={this.toggleList} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `event.stopPropagation()`. This will isolate the event to only this specific execution-block. So now when you click on the filter-icon, it will only trigger the designated event-handler.

```
  toggleList = (event) => {
    event.stopPropgation()
    console.log("filter handler");
    this.setState(prevState => ({ showList: !prevState.showList }));
  };
```

You'll also need to use it here as well:

```
  handleValueChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, data: any) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    let updated: any;
    if (data.checked) {
      updated = [...this.state.selected, data.name];
    } else {
      updated = this.state.selected.filter(v => v !== data.name);
    }
    this.setState({ selected: updated });
  };
```

And here:

```
 passSelectionToParent = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation()
    this.props.handleFilter(this.props.name, this.state.selected);
  };
```

Literally, anytime you have a click-event for a parent-markup and it has children mark-up that also have a click-event, you can use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the parent click-event from firing.

Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-gauss-wgf3t

Comment: This is just firing sort handler. Check sandbox

Comment: @vjr If you were to put this on `toggleList()` then the filter handler would be triggered. Seems to be working fine in my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-cherry-tu6yr

Comment: @vjr i don't know if its just me. but the speed to complile these sandboxes are ridiculously slow.

Comment: Could you check this behavior. On click of filter, dropdown opens and you check or uncheck, sort handler is getting fired . https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-glitter-np8iw

Comment: @vjr oh i see. So clicking one of the check boxes causes the sort handler to fire as well. We can literally do the same thing as we did above :)

Comment: same thing as in? Could you edit the code sandbox, and on click on apply also it should not fire sort handler

Comment: @vjr you're welcome. I've added a link to the sandbox as well, but it looks like you already updated your code :)

Comment: Would you be able to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253637/setting-a-property-of-an-object-inside-array-of-objects-based-on-a-match-react?

Comment: @vjr yup! just posted an answer to your new posy

Comment: Thanks again! It required a slight change! <b>!this.state.values.includes(item.initialVal)</b> you have negated the result, Instead it should be without negation. No worries! It gave me a clue:)

Comment: @vjr oh yeah! I had editted it cuz I was not sure if you wanted to include or not include :). Initially there was no negation haha. Sorry I was confused. I will change it back.

Comment: @vjr done haha. The other guy's answer is the same as mine. So it must be the right way to do this :)